# iOS: Creating buttons using IB vs. creating buttons programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

I'm a web and android developer, and now i'm learning iOS development, i noticed that if you want to build any view (let's say a button) you have to create it using `Interface Builder`, or you can make it happen programmatically by doing for instance :

```
UIButton *but= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [but addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [but setFrame:CGRectMake(52, 252, 215, 40)];
    [but setTitle:@"Login" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [but setExclusiveTouch:YES];
    [self.view addSubview:but];
```

But if you did that the button won't be visible in the `Storyboard`.

In android there are `XML` files where you can build your layouts whether with `drag and drop` or with xml programming(which i prefer) and both ways the button will be visible if you want to look at the layout.

But here in `iOS` i can't find a way to look at the `Storyboard` code.

I think what i'm asking is: is it possible to see the `Storyboard` code ? and what is the best approach for designing views in iOS ?

**NOTE** i researched a lot, but i'm new to `iOS` world so i found a lot of stuff that i don't recognize or understand yet.

Comment: Right click on your storyboard, open as in XCode. Else, it's up to you and primarly opinion based.

Comment: oh, i don't know why i haven't tried that, but do iOS developers build using XIB or just open the source code for storyboard and do their business programmatically ?

Comment: Mostly using XIB & Storyboard files..

Comment: There is no "storyboard code". There is code in iOS that reads storyboards and creates views according to the data in the storyboard, which is stored in XML format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Snapshot]

Right click on Main.storyboard then open it as Source code.

Answer (score 1):

[This blog post](http://codewithchris.com/xcode-using-storyboards-and-xibs-versus-creating-views-programmatically/) has an interesting discussion on how to decide whether to use Storyboards or XIBs to create views, or to create them programatically. Personally, I prefer using XIBs to set up the main layout as I can easily drag and drop the views and add constraints, and I have a more visual overview of my view controller. I then always have the option of making further changes programatically.

But then again, I think it's personal preference, so there's no *right* way.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, UI stuff made in code does not (unfortunately) reflect in the interface builder.

Whether or not to use the interface builder, do all UI "by hand" or a combination is a matter of personal preferences.

I personally prefer to do UI stuff in code unless I'm prototyping. This gives me more fine grained handling and I'm able to have my UI logic contained in one place.